# MATLAB analog filter impulse response

Tags: filter, matlab

MATLAB's `impz` is used to get the impulse response of a discrete time filter. `freqz` is used for the frequency response of a discrete time filter. `freqs` is used for the frequency response of a continuous time filter. But, there is no `imps` - how can I plot the impulse response of a continuous time filter without this?

Comment: Have a look at the `impulse` function.

Comment: Yep, that did it for me. You want to put that in an answer? Also mention how to get the linear system. I used the `tf` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a continuous time system the `impulse` function can be used to plot the impulse response. The system can be specified using zero-pole (`zpk`), state-space (`ss`) or transfer function (`tf`) notation.

For example:

```
sys = tf[1, [1 1]);
impulse(sys);
```